# Visual Studio 2012 or MTM for Administrative reports?

Tags: test-management, test-strategy, test-report, mtm

I'm creating a report for my manager to help track what stage in the testing process her testers are in.  We currently use `VS 2012` for the `development` and `MTM` for `test` writing.

I tried creating a `Query-based Test Suite` in `MTM`, that displays all tasks for certain `testers/projects` with `no linked Test Cases`.  I can't figure out how to output these results.

I can display all the tasks assigned to tester, but can't marry the requirement of `no test associated` to `backlog` item.

This sounds somewhat straightforward.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize a report or export it to a Word or Excel File using TFS API.

Comment: Why would the TFS API work better for the OP? Customized reports that can be exported are available without the TFS API - you need to say what the API adds to make this a useful answer.

Comment: TFS API only should be used for MTM Test Suite Export, MTM does not support export to any Office Tools with customized

Comment: MTM test suites are viewable in the TFS web portal - which does support export to Office tools. Test cases can be queried like any work item. Using the API seems excessive to me when MTM can't operate without TFS and the information can be accessed through TFS.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is to use the TFS Web Portal reports section and create a new report there using the SSRS report builder.

Alternatively, you can create a TFS query that gives you the information and connect to your TFS project with Excel, then link to that query.

Either way will get you that data you want.

Comment: Thank you!  I have not seen the Reporting section and just took a gander.  This may be just what I'm looking for.